# What does the road name 'Meend' mean in English?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I live in a road called 'Kells Meend' and for years I've been trying to find out what the word 'Meend' means.

[Here's the road name on Google maps.](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Berry+Hill,+Coleford,+Gloucestershire+GL16/@51.8098787,-2.6191926,18z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4871ba1badc351fb:0x19190afba7759dab)

And, on [Streetmap](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/map.srf?x=357425&y=212615&z=110&sv=kells%20meend&st=6&tl=Map%20of%20Kells%20Meend,%20Berry%20Hill,%20Coleford,%20Gloucestershire,%20GL16&searchp=ids.srf&mapp=map.srf) (if you scroll around)you can see other examples:

- Coleford Meend
- Bream's Meend

The area (The Forest of Dean) used to be known for coal mining and timber production so it might have something to do with that.

The only reference I can find is [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meend) but that refers to - 'In Hindustani music, meend refers to a glide from one note to another' - which, I suspect is not the meaning of the word in this context.

Anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: Seems as if @mplungjan has hit the nail on the head. I was about to ask if you were in Gloucestershire or Monmouth. But it would appear from the map that you are east of Offa's Dyke. If you go into the [county record office in Gloucester](http://www.gloucestershire.gov.uk/archives/article/107703/Archives-Homepage) there should be someone there who can point you to the history of this. They may well be able to provide books/links etc where you can find out more of the history. If they can't help try Monmouth. How romantic. I wish I lived in a *Meend* rather than a plain simple *Avenue*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking for [Meend etymology](https://www.google.com/search?q=Meend+etymology) I found

[The distribution and origin of meends in the Forest of Dean](http://www.academia.edu/9072562/The_distribution_and_origin_of_meends_in_the_Forest_of_Dean)

> There have been several interpretations of the origin of
>   meend.  The most current and now widely accepted is that to be found in Smith’s “Place-Names of Gloucestershire” (1964).
>   [...]  He considered that meend is derived from Old Welsh ‘minid’, meaning mountain’, and was rendered as munede during the medieval period, eventually occurring as meend through a variety of post-medieval forms such as myne and meene.
>   It has cognate forms along the Welsh Marches and in Wales as Mynydd.
>
> It came to be used to deﬁne an area of open space, often associated with the royal forest.

---

> ...I venture to think that this view rests upon insufﬁcient basis. First of all, such ridges as are in the Forest have always been called so: i.e. Serridge. (13th c. Seyrrudge); and, when the 13th c. Forest-Scribe referred to an exceptional hill, he frankly terms it "Mons." Not a Single instance of
>    Mynydd has survived in that peculiarly conservative region; whereas there are over twenty Meands. Secondly, wherever this term occurs it carries the sense of open unﬁlled, or common, land, throughout the Bailiwicks; in fact, it is identical with the Meanelands of Co. Kent: lands held in common (A.S. gemǽne).

As mentioned in comments, we have gemeente and Mient's in Dutch - stemming from uncultivated land for common use - viz. Commons...

Comment: What a great answer. I like the definition "The word is often used in association with “forest waste”. These areas lay outside the forest plantation inclosures and were historically exploited by local communities for grazing and as a source of bracken, gorse and brushwood." On the 1780 map with our house on it (and little else !), we're in between two 'arms' of forest much like we are today (as can be seen on the maps linked above).

Comment: Third link now - this page has gone to the top.

Comment: It also appears in English place names spelled "Mynd" (pronounced minned, rhyming with pinned). For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Mynd, and there is a Myndtown in Shropshire.

Comment: Very interesting; I see some similarity with the Dutch the word 'meent'. It is used as a street name across the Netherlands and dates back to the medieval period (also as mient, gemeynt) where is was used to define an area of uncultivated land for common use. It later became used to define pasture commons.

Comment: I know a few "De Mient" here in Holland...

Comment: I presume Smith has some good reason for this etymology, but it seems odd. It assumes that Welsh _minid/mynydd_ was borrowed into English and then—for some reason—suffered syncope of the final syllable and despirantisation of the final consonant, neither of which is typical for English _or_ Welsh. The Welsh word (whether written as ⟨minid⟩ in Old Welsh, ⟨myned mined mynid mynyd (etc.)⟩ in Middle Welsh, or ⟨mynydd⟩ in Modern Welsh) phonetically represents [ˈmɨnəð], which would most likely and straightforwardly yield English _minneth_ or something like that. _Meend_ has the wrong vowel, →

Comment: → the wrong number of syllables, and the wrong final consonant. But then I don’t have access to Smith’s work, so I don’t know what his full arguments are (and if the earlier English form _munede_ really is the same, it does look like it’s just an odd, random syncope).

Comment: @DeltaLima That looks at first glance more like it’s related to Dutch _gemeente_ (and thus also Latin _commūnis_) meaning ‘common’. The similarity to the Anglo-Cymric word here is then just a coincidence.

Comment: Oh! Reading on a bit further in the article linked to in this answer (p. 41ff.), it becomes clear that Ben Lennon (its author) **agrees that _meend_ is not from Brythonic /ˈmɨnəð/ at all**. In fact, he suggests that it is cognate with the Dutch word _gemeente_ (and presumably also _meent/mient_), deriving from OE _ġemǣne_ ‘common’ with a _d_-extension identical to the one seen in Dutch and German. It is thus basically _mean + d_.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it still falls under fair use. In any case the paper itself is a good resource for this question